# Finding Palindromes in Sentences Using Java

Tags: java, string, palindrome

I completed a program for my computer science class in which I had to write a program that got the user to input a word and the program would tell the user whether the word was a palindrome or not. I want to expand this so i can enter a sentence and the program would tell me how many words are palindromes and show me which ones are the palindromes. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Fill an array with the words to be tested, then pass them through your built algorithm and add 1 to your counter variable whenever a word is a palindrome, then finally print your counter...

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string is a palindrome we need to compare the word reversed and see if they are the same:

```
boolean isPalindrome = word.equals(new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString());
```

Now that you can check a single word, try to write a loop over all your words and add to a counter when you find one.

Comment: but would that work with user input, because i get the user to enter a full sentence.

Comment: try breaking the problem down into steps to see if you can get it to the point where you can check if one word is a palindrome.

Comment: I already created a program that determines if a word is a palindrome, I am trying to edit it to process a sentence to figure out how many palindromes are in the sentence and what they are.